# Spring Ignore Filter Chain for certain url

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

We have a bunch of filters setup which match against a base url such as the following:

```
    FilterRegistration.Dynamic characterEncoding = servletContext.addFilter("characterEncoding", characterEncodingFilter);
    characterEncoding.addMappingForUrlPatterns(dispatcherTypes, true, "/*");
```

I have a new open URL such as `/open/pages/` which I want to skip all these preconfigured filters.

I am used Spring with annotation based configuration, here is my security context rules:

```
http
        .csrf().disable()
                    .logout()
                        .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
                        .invalidateHttpSession(true)
                //Configures url based authorization
                .and()
                    .authorizeRequests()
                        .antMatchers(OpenPageDataController.OPEN_PAGE_MAPPING + "/**")
                        .hasIpAddress("127.0.0.1")
                .and()
                        .authorizeRequests()
                            //Anyone can access the urls
                            .antMatchers(
                                    "/auth/**",
                                    "/login",
                                    "/login/email/**",
                                    "/signup/**",
                            ).permitAll()
                            .antMatchers("/**").hasRole("USER")
```

Which would be the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding:

```
.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/open/pages/**").permitAll()
```

This will allow any resource under the `/open/pages/` hierarchy to be accessed by a non authenticated user.

Comment: This doesn't answer my question unfortunately. The problem is that I need to skip the HTTP request filters that are bound to /** for this URL.